# How can an electric motor car have a turbo?

Tags: motor, induction-motor

I am not familiar with all the different vehicles on the road nowdays but I have read descriptions of electric vehicles. i.e ( EV) that are turbo powered.

How can an EV  be "tubo" when turbo refers to increased pressure? The concept of pressure has no meaning for EV. Perhaps the question is off topic and not condidered a question about electricity.

Comment: Please [edit] to give a proper quotation and reference to such a description so we can check the context.

Comment: Old computers ('90s) used to have a turbo button.  Pressing it would run the CPU at max clock at the expense of power.  Maybe in EV context it makes the car go really fast at the expense of power.  Kind of like the opposite of ECO-Mode in Nissan Leaf.

Comment: Аn electrical motor can heat up if you give it more current. More current is more output mechanical power. Perhaps at the same time as a larger current supply, cooling is also needed. Overcurrent + heating + cooling = turbo (I think so).

Comment: I think overcurrent is turbo, but without additional control the motor can be damaged.

Comment: Without a proper quotation and context we can only guess. My guess is that the use of "turbo" by Porsche is pure marketing BS. There may be someone planning to build a turbine generator hybrid. There are IC engines with electrically driven turbochargers. I believe the Tesla "Ludicrous Mode" simply turns up on a current limit that prevents the motor from delivering it's full torque capability in order to get more milage from a charge.

Comment: @Aaron That button actually did the exact opposite( at least in most cases). It was intended to be used with older games/ software where it was based of a lower clock speed. So actually it slowed the main clock down. But in doing so made older software run faster. I saw this on one of Linus's videos.

Comment: @bunker89320 Took me down a rabbit hole with that one. It looks like it started out like you say, but then a few years later converted to "sane" configurations, where turbo was faster cpu clock.  Being a young'en I came on the PC scene when it had already converted.

Comment: @Charles Cowie. thank you. I accepted the answer below. I got stupid and looked at Porsche's advertising. Should have known better. Turbo should not be used to describe an electric motor just as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely just marketing jargon to mean "powerful". Sort of like how Tesla calls its high-power charging stations "superchargers".

As you said, it's definitely nothing to do with a turbocharger on an internal combustion engine. There's no similar concept for electric motors. Simply higher current in --> higher torque out.

Comment: Thank you @Luke. I am not sure why the call was closed. You answered the question very well and very clearly. The concept of "turbo" does not apply to electric motors. That's all there is to it.  Thank you for clarifying that. I was bamboozled by marketing.

Comment: The Question is closed to answers, so I have to post this as a response. The use of "turbo" in this case is meant figuratively, not literally. In a true "turbo" situation with a compressor, the boost in power is not permanent, it has consequences. Similarly with an EV that is being operated with VFD technology,you can "tweak" the ratio of voltage and frequency going to the motor in order to increase torque, but doing so ALSO will increase the heat in the motor. So SIMILAR to a "turbo", you get more power TEMPORARILY when needed.